# É melhor repetir campo ou join para acessar o relacionamento?

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, sql

Olá, pensando em performance e também boas práticas, qual seria o ideal nesse cenário?

3 Objetos:
- Empresa
- Pessoa que está representando a empresa
- Visita (objeto referente a uma visita comercial de um vendedor)

Para eu exibir a informação ao usuário seria melhor eu deixar como na imagem abaixo? respeitando a hierarquia ou poderia repetir dados, colocando o id do cliente também na tabela de visitas para não precisar dar um join?

[image: Modelagem exemplo para fins didáticos]

Comment: Já vi usarem das duas formas, cada uma com seus prós e contras. De acordo com as boas práticas, o ideal é deixar tudo separado. Mas pra facilitar as consultas, pode-se utilizar os dados repetidos, agilizando a busca no banco. Fica a seu critério.

Comment: Já lei a respeito de [tag:normalização] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é utilizar o JOIN, pois caso você coloque o id do cliente na tabela VISITA você estará criando uma relação que é redundante, visto que você consegue chegar a mesma informação utilizando o JOIN através da relação entre as outras tabelas (VISITA, REPRESENTANTE_CLIENTE e CLIENTE). Isso deve ser evitado segundo a literatura e as boas práticas.